# How to merge pandas string in python ( join sql alike ) ?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge ( or left join sql alike ) for 2 table ( df1 , df2 ) using string value "name" to merge .. similar to sql :

```
select * from df1 left join df2 using (name) ;
```

in python I can use integer to merge / but when I use "name" which is string I got an error.

```
df_new = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',on = ['name']).sort(['max_value','name'],ascending=[0,0])
```

This work fine if I use integer **on**  , but when I try to use merge table with name ( string ) i got this error below , How can I fix this issue ?

***error : string indices must be integers***

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',on = 'name').sort(['max_value','name'],ascending=[0,0])
```

Notice `on = 'name'` rather than `on = ['name']`.